# How to restore full array again after splice an element by condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, momentjs

I have a dynamic table and want to have a random array element for each day of a month. For each day I might need to remove an array element by condition, but I need to have the original array again for checking and picking for the next day.

The following function includes the iteration and conditions, but it's removing the array elements for all iterations once it's fired.

```
function generateRandomSchedule(month) {
    if(!month) {
        month = localStorage.getItem('currentDutyMonth');
    }
    const monthNumber = moment().month(month).format('M');
    const year = localStorage.getItem('currentYear');
    const daysInMonth = moment(`${year}-${monthNumber}`, 'YYYY-MM').daysInMonth();

    for(let i=1; i<daysInMonth+1; i++) {
        let date = `${moment(i, 'D').format('DD')}.${monthNumber}.`;
        const keys = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(key => key.includes(date) && !key.startsWith(month));
        keys.forEach((key) => {
            let keyValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
            if(key.includes('Urlaub') && dutyUserArray.includes(keyValue)) {
                let index = dutyUserArray.indexOf(keyValue);
                if(index > -1) {
                    dutyUserArray.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
            if(key.includes('Spaet') && dutyUserArray.includes(keyValue)) {
                let index = dutyUserArray.indexOf(keyValue);
                if (index > -1) {
                    dutyUserArray.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
        })

        let randomName = dutyUserArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * dutyUserArray.length)];
        let objectId = document.getElementById(`tdMa${date}`);
        objectId.value = randomName;

        localStorage.setItem(`${month}_tdMa${date}`, randomName);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to undo the splice once a `randomName` is chosen, or a better solution than `splice()` in order to keep the original array.

Comment: You can simply [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array? Or clone it before your `forEach()`? It's a little unclear what you're doing.

Comment: @pilchard thank you for the reminder. Yes of course `filter()` is the better option in this case. Don't know why I didn't think about this.